# Loading small jpeg files very quickly

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-glide, android-bitmap, leanback

I have implemented a custom version of bitmap loader. I have an auto scroll list of images
of movies. When the user presses and holds the d-pad i start scrolling the list at Speed 1. We have speed 2 and 3 which scroll the list very fast so I have to load the images very fast.
So I created a circular list to load 50 images first then based on the current position I load the 25 images and discard the older 25 images.

I also tried the Glide preload https://muyangmin.github.io/glide/int/recyclerview.html but this does not work well in speed 3  and shows empty tiles instead of images

When I am doing the profiling i am seeing that 395MB memory is used by FinalizerRefrenace [image: Memory profiler]

FinalizerReference is held by the bitmaps I am using.

How can I fix the memory leak?  I tried calling the `recycle` when the user closed the seek, still no luck.

Images i have are very small in size, mostly 10kb. Why do they take 100 Mb in memory?
Is there any other library I can use to show these images  on a fast scrolling list for android TV?

Comment: "Images i have are very small in size, mostly 10kb. Why do they take 100 Mb in memory?" -- [JPEG is a compressed file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG). Software needs to decompress it to render it on the screen. "How can I fix the memory leak?" -- [there may not be a leak](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57027001/115145).

Comment: The two big things I'd be looking at:  1-  make sure you're using RecyclerView or similar, and not just adding new views for each row.  2-  make sure you do not store the bitmap anywhere in your model.  At most, store a WeakReference to the bitmap and reload if needed.  3-  if you have any caching layer, make sure that its working properly, that it does not keep references around longer than needed, and that its limited to not just a number of images but a max memory size of image.